# What is to prevent the same user having two accounts that "vote each other up"?

Tags: discussion

What is to prevent the same user having two accounts that "vote each other up"?.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35989/how-can-you-detect-if-users-have-created-sock-puppet-accounts

Comment: Oh well, maybe that edit was not on purpose; I removed my downvote. Still: know that folks are watching you, and any sock puppet you create.

Comment: @Arjan: my mistake, the edit was done by me...downvote if you like...sorry about that!

Comment: @studio, did you just add the very same comment again, and then delete that? I just [got notified for it](http://i.imgur.com/DaBQh.png)!

Comment: @Arjan: no! I have not been on this question for a long time!

Comment: Hmmm, @studio, I guess *anyone* could have posted the same comment and then deleted that, given [Deleted comments persist in the global inbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/deleted-comments-persist-in-the-global-inbox/65792#comments-657920), just to play a trick on me! I guess I'll never know... (If any developer sees this: according to [meta.stackoverflow.com/inbox](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/inbox)  the comment id is 215105, different from the original comment above.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are script that runs each day that can detect such scenario and reverse all the vote if a such thing is detected.

The detail of the those detection script are unknown (except for the developer) for obvious reason.

Also, if you think someone has been doing that (and the vote haven't been reversed), you can flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: ***except** for the developer :-)

Comment: Now I know why Jeff has such a high rep! ;)

Comment: Security through obscurity, I feel safer already. :-)

Comment: @dalle, how is this related to *security*?

Comment: @Arjan: Flaw in algorithm leads to mischief sock puppet getting much reputation which in turn gives knowingly incorrect answers to questions (that people trusts because of sock puppets high reputation) which opens up for potential attacks? Conspiracy theory? Yes, perhaps.

Comment: @dalle If you know the algorythm, it's a lot easier to go around it, then if you have to guess what it is and you are also more likely to get caught.